# htaccess on hosted website in MVC architecture

Tags: php, .htaccess, web-hosting

This works fine on localhost:
but doesn't work on my hosted site (by Hostinger.fr)

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond expr "%{REQUEST_URI} -strmatch '*admin/*'"
RewriteRule (.*) $1  [L] 
RewriteCond expr "%{REQUEST_URI} -strmatch '*journal/*'"
RewriteRule (.*) $1  [L]
RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
```

these lines are followed (after process) by an other htaccess heading the webroot directory :

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

It uses to show me 1st page as index.php exists in the webroot directory there but doesn't show internal pages.
I use a MVC structure to code the site and the invoked program is not directly indicated
By clicking an option in the menu shown by the index.php page, it only shows me an empty page with a message "No input file specified."
The webroot index.php is not invoked (like in the first time) to proceed in developping the true program to invoke.

Could anyone kindly suggest me what needs to be done in the .htaccess ?

NB : Hostinger wants that "Rewrite Base /" command must be placed in the first place

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have time to test your htaccess, but there are some things you can try:

1. Make sure your file permissions are correct. For most host providers, the htaccess (and all other files) must have 644 permissions to work
2. Check if the rewrite module of Apache is installed and activated. Generally this is enabled by default on host providers, but maybe some providers will require you to manually activate the modules on their control panel
3. Check your file system directory tree and make sure that there isn't any other htaccess file in a parent directory that could overwrite the behaviour of your htaccess

For example, if you a have file in `/home/your_user/public_html/.htaccess` and a file in `/home/your_user/public_html/my_sub_app/.htaccess`, then if the first htaccess has an instruction like:

```
<Directory>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>
```

It will prevent the second htaccess to overwrite the behaviour

Comment: Thank you for your research leads but 
I have already verified them and everything is good at Hostinger. 
The orders suggested for the first lines of the htaccess file cause only an error 500